# Error in linking C++ static library with android ndk(Error: file format not recognized)

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I am trying to include static cpp library in android. This library is already compiled(**on mac os**) and i have its include files.

Here is my `Android.mk` file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
 include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
    include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
    LOCAL_MODULE:= utils 
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= libUtils.a 
    LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/utils 
    include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY) 

    include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
    LOCAL_MODULE := sample 
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := sample_cpp.cpp 
    LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH) 
    LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES :=  utils
    LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog 
    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and here is `Application.mk` file

```
APP_STL := stlport_static
APP_CPPFLAGS = -fexceptions
```

but whenever it try to compile it using NDK i get the error

**(Path of file)/libUtils.a: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status**

Comment: can you provide the output of `file libUtils.a`?

Comment: sorry but i cant get you? output?

Comment: Was your library compiled for android? If the library contains code for another type of processor (instruction-set), it won't work!

Comment: @bert-jan library was compiled with xcode on mac os. and working fine for iphone

Comment: You need to compile it for Android using Cygwin for example, have you done that?

Comment: @donalRafferty ya i tried that but i got some compilation errors.(as it couldn.t find few includes from cygwin on windows and from terminal on mac as well). thats why i decided to go with this compiled version of library.

Comment: Which version of the NDK are you using? Google Crystax NDK to see if that version of the NDK has the includes you require.

Answer (score 5):

From the comments and so on it sounds like you trying to use a non arm version of the library. You should build the library with the ndk. The documentation has even documentation on how to do that.

For example building sigc++ could be like (from a project of mine, where sigc++ resides in the sigc++ subdirectory)

```
# SIGC++ Library built as static library
LOCAL_MODULE := sigc
LOCAL_PATH = $(CURRENT_DIR)
LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cc

LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=    sigc++/signal.cc       sigc++/signal_base.cc  sigc++/trackable.cc 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES +=    sigc++/functors/slot_base.cc  sigc++/adaptors/lambda/lambda.cc 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += sigc++/connection.cc sigc++/functors/slot.cc

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := sigc++

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

But you should really read how the compiling linking works. I am afraid building for android with ndk is more low level than using Xcode or Msvc.

Comment: +1 dude for explanation. let me see the doccumentation. and then try to compile it.